# The "Type" attribute of Image in "Sitecore Select Media" popup is showing as "Image" instead of "Jpeg"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-media-library

When I click on **Browse link** of any image field in my sitecore 8.1 instance, the type of Image is displaying as "Image" instead of "Jpeg". I guess some setting went wrong. Please point out me in right direction.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but there's different Sitecore types for different image extensions.  PNGs (for instance) are stored with the Image type.

Comment: Hi Alex, but for jpeg type images also, it is showing "Type-Image"

Comment: If you upload a new Jpeg image, does the type change to type-image?

Comment: Hi @HishaamNamooya, it is fine for Jpeg images. I am not aware that type of png's will be image in media library.

Comment: Thanks @alex for ur support

Comment: Thanks @HishaamNamooya for ur support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad. It is occuring only for png images. It is fine absolutely for Jpeg images.Thanks for ur support.